# Angular 7 Firebase email login auth doesn't work

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-authentication, angularfire2

So, I managed to register my users using the email and password successfully following this Firebase Auth doc: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/password-auth

But when trying to log in using the same credentials, I just get some weird error in Chrome console:

[image]

I never seen error like this and don't even understand what it means or what does it want from me.

Terminal console throws this:

`src/app/login/login.component.ts(6,16): error TS2580: Cannot find name 'require'. Do you need to install type definitions for node? Try "npm i @types/node".`

`src/app/register/register.component.ts(5,16): error TS2580: Cannot find name 'require'. Do you need to install type definitions for node? Try`npm i @types/node`.`

`src/app/services/auth.service.ts(5,10): error TS2305: Module '"/Users/laimis/Desktop/Steen Angular chapters/angular-draganddrop/node_modules/rxjs/Observable"' has no exported member 'Observable'.`

Code:

register.component.html

```
<div class="container">
<form [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="signInWithEmail()">
    <div class="form-group">
       <label for="email">Email</label>
        <input type="email" class="form-control" formControlName="email">
       <div *ngIf="form.controls.email.touched
        && !form.controls.email.valid" class="alert alert-danger">
            Email is required
       </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
    <label for="password">Password</label>
    <input type="password" class="form-control" formControlName="password">
    <div *ngIf="form.controls.password.touched && form.controls.password.errors">
        <div *ngIf="form.controls.password.errors.invalidLogin"
class="alert alert-danger">
            Email or password is invalid.
        </div>
        <div *ngIf="form.controls.password.errors.required"
class="alert alert-danger">
            Password is required.
        </div>
        <div *ngIf="form.controls.password.errors.cannotContainSpace"
class="alert alert-danger">
            Password cannot contain space.
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Register</button>

</form>
</div>
```

register.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { PasswordValidator } from '../login/passwordValidator';
import { AuthService } from '../services/auth.service';
var firebase = require('firebase');

@Component({
  selector: 'app-register',
  templateUrl: './register.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./register.component.css']
})
export class RegisterComponent {
  form: FormGroup;

  constructor(fb: FormBuilder, private authService: AuthService) {
    this.form = fb.group({
  email:['',Validators.required ],
  password:['',Validators.compose([Validators.required,
    PasswordValidator.cannotContainSpace])]
    })
   }

   signInWithEmail() {
     firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(this.form.controls['email'].value, this.form.controls['password'].value)
      .catch(function(error) {
        // Handle Errors here.
        var errorCode = error.code;
        var errorMessage = error.message;
        // ...
      });
     console.log(this.form.controls['email'].value);
   }
}
```

login.component.html

```
<div class="container">
<form [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="login()">
    <div class="form-group">
       <label for="email">Email</label>
        <input type="email" class="form-control" formControlName="email">
       <div *ngIf="form.controls.email.touched
        && !form.controls.email.valid" class="alert alert-danger">
            Email is required
       </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
    <label for="password">Password</label>
    <input type="password" class="form-control" formControlName="password">
    <div *ngIf="form.controls.password.touched && form.controls.password.errors">
        <div *ngIf="form.controls.password.errors.invalidLogin"
class="alert alert-danger">
            Email or password is invalid.
        </div>
        <div *ngIf="form.controls.password.errors.required"
class="alert alert-danger">
            Password is required.
        </div>
        <div *ngIf="form.controls.password.errors.cannotContainSpace"
class="alert alert-danger">
            Password cannot contain space.
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Login</button>
</form>
</div>
```

login.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

import { PasswordValidator } from './passwordValidator';
import { LoginService } from './login.service';
var firebase = require('firebase');

@Component({
    selector:'login',
    templateUrl: 'login.component.html'
})
export class LoginComponent  {

    form: FormGroup;

    constructor(fb: FormBuilder, private _loginService: LoginService){

        this.form = fb.group({
            email:['',Validators.required ],
      password:['',Validators.compose([Validators.required,
PasswordValidator.cannotContainSpace])]
        })
    }

    login(){
   firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(this.form.controls['email'].value, this.form.controls['password'].value).catch(function(error) {
  // Handle Errors here.
  var errorCode = error.code;
  var errorMessage = error.message;
  // ...
});
    }
}
```

EDIT: For now I was just following official firebase docs for auth, but after checking some online tutorials for firebase email auth, I see everyone using AngularFire2 instead of Firebase API. AngularFire2 seems so much more complicated and their github auth docs are really bad, there is just one instance example and nothing more, but these tutorials seems to throw many methods for auth on AngularFire.auth instance. I don't get it where they come from as GitHub docs don't cover anything.

Which one should I be using?

Comment: I would use the angularfire2 package. You could use just firebase and roll your own services. Up to you.

Answer (score 0):

change your firebase import statement from:

```
var firebase = require('firebase');
```

to:

```
import { auth } from 'firebase/app';
```

then you can implement your sign in flow as such:

### login.component.ts

```
constructor(private authService: AuthService) {}

async login() {
  var email = this.form.controls['email'].value;
  var password = this.form.controls['password'].value;
  await this.authService.loginWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);
}
```

### auth.service.ts (using firebase directly):

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { auth } from 'firebase/app';

export interface User {
  uid: string;
  displayName?: string;
  email: string;
  photoURL?: string;
}

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class AuthService {

  async loginWithEmailAndPassword(email: string, password: string) {
    return auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
           .then(result => {
             if (result.user) {
               var user = result.user;
             }
           })
           .catch(error => {
             console.error(error);
           });
  }

  async signOut() {
    await auth().signOut();
    console.log('You've been signed out!');
  }

}
```

### auth.service.ts (using AngularFire2):

```
import { Injectable, NgZone } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';
import { switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { AngularFireAuth } from '@angular/fire/auth';
import { AngularFirestore } from '@angular/fire/firestore';

export interface User {
  uid: string;
  displayName?: string;
  email: string;
  photoURL?: string;
}

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class AuthService {

  user: Observable<User>;

  constructor(
    private afAuth: AngularFireAuth, 
    private afs: AngularFirestrore,
    private zone: NgZone,
    private router: Router
    ) {
      this.user = this.afAuth.authState.pipe(switchMap(user => {
        if (user) {
          return this.afs.doc<User>(`users/${user.uid}`).valueChanges();
        } else {
          return of(null);
        }
   }));
  }

  async registerWithEmailAndPassword(email: string, password: string) {
    var regResult = await this.afAuth.auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
      .catch(error => {
        var errorCode = error.code;
        if (errorCode == 'auth/email-already-in-use') {
          console.error('Email already registered, please login...');
          localStorage.setItem('userEmail', email);
          this.zone.run(() => this.router.navigate(['login']));
        }
      });
      if (regResult != null) {
        var user = this.afAuth.auth.currentUser;
        await this.createNewUserDoc(regResult);
        this.router.navigate(['']);
      }
  }

  async loginWithEmailAndPassword(email: string, password: string) {
    return this.afAuth.auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
           .then(result => {
             if (result.user) {
               var user = result.user;
             }
           })
           .catch(error => {
             console.error(error);
           });
  }

  async createNewUserDoc(regResult) {
    console.log('Creating new user doc in firestore...');
    return await this.afs.doc(`users/${regResult.user.uid}`).set({
      uid: regResult.user.uid,
      email: regResult.user.email
    }, { merge: true })
    .catch(error => console.error('Error creating user doc: ', error));
  }

  async signOut() {
    await this.afAuth.auth.signOut();
    console.log('You've been signed out!');
    this.router.navigate(['login']);
  }

}
```

### register.component.ts:

```
constructor(private authService: AuthService) {}

signInWithEmail() {
  var email = this.form.controls['email'].value;
  var password = this.form.controls['password'].value;
  this.authService.registerWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);
}
```